# How to get access to Dockerfile of a docker image?

Tags: linux, docker, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, docker-image

Below is the docker image:

https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/distroless/GLOBAL/base

Goal is to find, if this image is based on debian or rpm based Linux distro.

---

1. How to find the Dockerfile for this image?
2. What does distroless image mean?

Answer (score 2):

> How to find the Dockerfile for this image?

There is no Dockerfile for that image.

The `gcr.io/distroless/base` image is built from [this repository](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless). If you read through the `README`, you'll find:

> ### How do I use distroless images?
>
> These images are built using bazel, but they can also be used through other Docker image build tooling.

Bazel is a build tool that can be [used to create Docker images](https://blog.bazel.build/2015/07/28/docker_build.html).

> What does distroless image mean?

That means the image isn't based on any particular distribution; it includes only a [minimal set of files](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/blob/main/base/README.md) so that the final image contains only what is strictly necessary to run your application:

- ca-certificates
- A /etc/passwd entry for a root user
- A /tmp directory
- tzdata
- glibc
- libssl
- openssl